# Convert to Decimal after Bulk Insert on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters, bulkinsert

I'm loading a CSV file into SQL Server using the bulk insert and therefore all decimal data is brought in as text. Now I need to convert the fields that are decimal to decimal (10,2).  Do you know the syntax?  Also, I want to set all fields in the table with this file to one ID.  Is the syntax ID =

Comment: What bulk insert technique are you using? Management Studio? `SqlBulkCopy`? Most ways of doing bulk insert allow you to specify the data type of the incoming field, so you can directly import decimals at the right precision without having them as text first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bulk insert, then the field types will be whatever they are in the receiving table.  If a table is being created, ie through Import Wizard, then you can adjust the field types in the wizard.

If you're just using an all-string staging table, then you can use `CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(10,2))`.  If you're applying a constant to every row in a table, you can just use `ID = 1` or whatever you want the `ID` to be.

You can `ALTER` and `UPDATE` to manipulate your existing table, but it's typically easier to either set the table up with the proper types first, or `SELECT INTO` a new table with the proper types from the all-text staging table.